# return from list given one or another condition in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have `list = [1,2,3,'hello','bye',10,11,12,12.2,12.3]` I want to return the elements that are in an odd index (zero based) OR they are integers. The idea is to make it the code as simple as possible.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Does `1.0` count as an integer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *list comprehension*:

```
[x for i,x in enumerate(lst) if i%2 == 1 or isinstance(x,int)]
```

Here we make use of `enumerate(..)` to generate tuples `(i,x)` with the index (zero-based) and the element. The `if` in the list filters: only elements where `i%2 == 1` (odd index) or where `x` is an instance of `int` are allowed. For these elements, we add `x` to the result.

The result is:

```
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(lst) if i%2 == 1 or isinstance(x,int)]
[1, 2, 3, 'hello', 10, 11, 12, 12.3]
```

Please do **not use `list` as variable name**: it is the name of a class, so by using `list`, you can no longer use `list(..)`. This answer works with `lst`.